# How to set the Key as Product name rather than application Id in Windows Registry

Tags: install4j

I want to use the entry name in Windows registry as the full name of the product not the application Id. Is there any way to configure this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Installer->Update Options, you can set a custom application ID, also an alphanumeric one.